# why does apt choose lower version of a package?

Tags: apt

Why my system choose 3103 instead of 3143?!

apt-cache policy sublime-text

```
sublime-text:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3103
  Version table:
     3143 0
        500 https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/ Packages
     3103 0
        700 http://extra.linuxmint.com/ qiana/main amd64 Packages
```

from apt preferences

```
500 < P <=990 : causes a version to be installed unless there is a version available belonging to the target release or the installed version is more recent
```

Shouldn't be that the 3143>3103 results in 3143 the actual candidate? Why it choose 3103 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It explains it right there.

If a new version of the the package isn't already installed - OK, assuming that is correct there is no newer version already installed

It would appear that you are using Mint so the v3103 is the target release's version, so it meets the condition to override a similarly prioritized package.  So that really doesn't apply here.

500 is not "greater than 500 and less than or equal to 990".

So the v3103 is the version to install.

Comment: so the "target release" actually means the current distro?

Comment: @Wang - yes.  Distribution provided packages v 3rd party